# How do I get the VM information presented in JConsole?

Tags: java, debugging, virtual-machine, jconsole

Starting *JConsole*, selecing a process and then and heading over to *VM Summary*, one can see a lot of VM information, such as:

- Number of live threads
- Number of current classes loaded
- Compilation time
- Current heap size
- Total threads started

Is there I can access that information inside a Java application? If so, how?

Update: 
Here is an image http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/images/summarytab.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the beast is "Java Management Extension (JMX)".

Here is a "[Getting Started](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jmx.html)" overview from oracle. You'll have to implement a *JMX Manager* to read the published internals from the JVM or from other instrumented applications.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/ExampleofusingthejavalangmanagementAPItosortthreadsbyCPUusage.htm

enjoy